# How can I support Sitecorians in Ukraine?

Tags: discussion

Please let me know how can I support the community in Ukraine?

Together we can make a huge difference. #WeAreSitecore #WeStandWithUkraine

Answer (score 1):

## Sitecore Ukraine Fund

Sitecore has set up a Ukraine Fund to provide immediate and direct assistance for the Sitecore employees and their extended families in Ukraine. Please note that Sitecore intends to match all donations to this fund so your support will go twice as far.

You can donate here to the Sitecore Ukraine Fund: https://www.sitecore.com/ukrainefund

Even if you cannot donate yourself please re-share the message from our CEO to help reach others in the community.

LinkedIn: https://lnkd.in/daXyRCa6

Twitter: https://twitter.com/Tzikakis/status/1498640809167495169

## One EPAM

*"We stand united with our friends, colleagues, their families and all communities that have been affected by the war in Ukraine and the impact in the surrounding areas.
We are, and we will always be, ONE EPAM. So many of you have already jumped into action with efforts on the ground and volunteering your support, and have asked what more you can do. Thank you for what you have already done to meet our #1 priority – relentlessly doing all we can to keep all of our people safe.
These five giving opportunities below are five more concrete and global ways we can help the urgent humanitarian crisis in the region."*

https://epam.benevity.org/community

## Other ways to help

**Please add here the option you know about. This is a Community Wiki.**